# Vim Pandoc & Headers

Tags: formatting, plugin-system, filetype-markdown, plugin-vim-pandoc

When using vim-pandoc, I'm having some funny behavior with headers:

For instance,

if I position the cursor on a word and press `v-a-w` and then `<localleader> - i`, I get italics.

if I position the cursor on a word and press `v-a-w` and then `<localleader> - b`, I get bold.

However, if I position the cursor on a word and press `v-a-w` and then `<localleader> - #`, I get `No String Under Cursor`.

Is this the wrong way to assign a block of text to a header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read vim-pandoc's help (`:h pandoc.txt`) you will see, in the section called `*vim-pandoc-keyboard-module*`, this line:

```
<localleader>#*     apply header (accepts a count) [n]
```

Notice the `[n]` at the end of the line - it means the map is *only* available when in normal mode. This probably means the map action applies to the whole current line.

Comment: I _did_ read the vim-pandoc help and I _did_  see that line.  My confusion was mistaking visual mode as an equivalent mode to normal mode in this context.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see. Based on your last two questions then, it seems you are quickly running for a full vim setup tailored (at least) for markdown/pandoc, but the editor itself won't let you run *that* fast :) But maybe I'm wrong; in any case, good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much...I've never had so much fun editing text!